# Contactless Smartcard response only to first APDU command

Tags: smartcard, rfid, apdu

I´m reading SmartCard- Mastercard with RC530 but same problem in RC522.
Problem is response everytime only on the forst command.
I send :

```
status =Request();

status =Anticoll();

status =Select();

status =RATS();

// send first APDU 

status=Command_Send(21,Transceive);//{0x02,0x00,0xA4,0x04,0x00,0x0E,0x32,0x50,0x41,0x59,0x2E,0x53,0x59,0x53,0x2E,0x44,0x44,0x46,0x30,0x31,0x00+crc};

// respond OK Mastercard Debit

response OK = 6F 35 84 E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 23 BF 0C 20 61 1E 4F 07 A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 50 10 44 45 42 49 54 20 4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 87 01 01 90 00

// Next Select File APDU

status=Command_Send(14,Transceive)//0x02,0x00,0xA4,0x04,0x00,0x07,0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x10,0x10,0x00+crc 

// Card don´t respond

response = 00
```

When I try send first Select File, the card respons was OK too.
I try send twice the same command, to the secound no response. 
But I need send more APDU for read records etc. 
I don´t know why Card dont respond on any next APDU commands, only for the first.
Any Idea?

Comment: Hi, just a minor detail: when you paste code into the question, you can select all of it and click the `{ }` button. This will give proper formatting to your code and it will be easier to read. Someone is editing your question now doing exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

problem is cleared. Problem was PCB byte where block number must be toggled for every command. In the ISO14443 protocol the explanation are very poor.

Thanx.